Who are the Green Lanterns and Guardians depicted in "Batman: The Dawnbreaker"?
I've been reading Batman: The Dawnbreaker, a tie-in to the Dark Nights: Metal event from DC Comics. Let me give you a quick rundown: Bruce Wayne becomes a Green Lantern, but instead of fighting for justice like the Green Lantern Corps, he goes full Punisher mode, taking out criminals and villains left and right. Needless to say, the Green Lantern Corps ain't too happy about this, so they step in to try and stop Bruce Wayne.
In the panels I've attached, you can see several Green Lanterns and Guardians of the Universe attempting to stop Bruce Wayne:


According to the DC Database wiki, the known Lanterns in these panels are Apros (the onion guy), Chaselon (the crystalline one), Galius Zed (Humpty Dumpty vibes), Kilowog (muscular), Salakk (the red seahorse lookalike), Tomar-Re (the bird-like dude with a fin on his head), and one of the Guardians, Ganthet.
But there are several other Lanterns and Guardians that aren't identified. In the first panel, we've got an eye-for-a-head Lantern with a thin neck, a blue-faced Lantern with stripes on their head, a squid Lantern, a fishbowl helmet Lantern with jellyfish arms, a shark-looking Lantern, a Lantern with a huge violet head and no nose, a manta-ray/frog Lantern, and an insectoid Lantern with dragonfly-like wings, among others.
In the second panel (where the illustrations are less detailed), we've got what seems to be a long-haired Lantern with a superhero cape, an underarm wings Lantern, a Chinese cabbage head Lantern, a seemingly human Lantern with a flat top haircut, a collared Lantern, a Lantern with four arms (not Salakk), a Lantern with red skin, an insect Lantern that looks like a grasshopper, and some more that I wasn't able to include a description of here.
Does anyone know who these Green Lanterns and Guardians of the Universe are in Batman: The Dawnbreaker?

I thought the ring was supposed to be able to reject a Green Lantern gone rogue (except Sinestro who found a new power source)?

The round crystalline Lantern is Chaselon the Green Lantern of Sector 1416.
Wiki claims "there are only 5 surviving Guardians: Ganthet, last of the original Guardians, Sayd, last of the reborn Guardians, Rami the renegade guardian, Zalla, and Paalko, last of the Templar guardians." - but this pic has six, so who knows on that one.

@Clockwork This Bruce Wayne had so much willpower that the darkness in him overrided the ring. He effectively "hacked" the ring.

Aah, it's the Dawnbreaker from the Dark Multiverse saga
